# How can I compare 2 tables in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I compare 2 tables with the same rows, but different data?

The tables are something like this: 
1. Table price_old:

```
|-----------------------|
| id | price1 | price2  | 
|-----------------------|
| 1  |   12   |   12    |
|-----------------------|
| 2  |   12   |   55    |
------------------------|
| 3  |   12   |   40    |
-------------------------
```

The tables are something like this:
2. Table price_old:

```
|-----------------------|
| id | price1 | price2  | 
|-----------------------|
| 1  |   12   |   12    |
|-----------------------|
| 2  |   13   |   40    |
------------------------|
| 3  |   10   |   40    |
-------------------------
```

The Result should look like this:
3. Table Result:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| id  | price1_old | price1_new | price2_old | price2_new  | 
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 2   |   12       |     13     |      55    |    40       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 3   |   13       |     10     |      40    |    40       |
```

Comment: So, the rows to compare are matched based on the `id` values? And then the rows to report are those where `price1` or `price2` (or both) are different. And we don't have to consider missing rows from either table?

Comment: yeah, they are based on the value  `id`. And right, no rows are missing in the tables, they are completly identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, joining on the id and filtering out occurrences where at least one price is different:

```
SELECT 
old.id,
old.price1 as price1_old,
old.price2 as price2_old,
new.price1 as price1_new,
new.price2 as price2_new
FROM price_old as old
LEFT JOIN price_new as new on old.id=new.id
WHERE old.price1<>new.price1 
OR old.price2<>new.price2
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @KevinLiss happy to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

This is might be an approach:

```
SELECT  'TableName' AS `set`, r.*
FROM    robot r
WHERE   ROW(r.col1, r.col2, …) NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    TableName2
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT  'TableName2' AS `set`, t.*
FROM    tbd_robot t
WHERE   ROW(t.col1, t.col2, …) NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    TableName1
    )
```

Comment: In SQL Server ( the system i´m workin on) there´s no function like `ROW()`

Comment: That can't not be possible! Maybe you missing something.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Alex SQL Server 2012